# In a non browser scenario, What advantages Websockets gives over HTTP?

Tags: http, websocket, xmpp

I understand that websockets works on a higher level in network stack and should not be compared with a normal socket. Websocket calls should be ideally compared with HTTP, when we talk about performance. However, I am still not convinced why one would choose webosockets. Why websocket tunnel is a faster approach than normal HTTP over TCP? Is it better than XMPP in performance?

Comment: I think the main advantage is that WebSockets start life as HTTP, so they operate on standard HTTP ports, which are usually open in firewalls. Also, WebSocket is a binary protocol so may provide other advantages over HTTP's largely textual nature.